# How to do HTML/CSS form helpers/popover

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am currently trying to figure out how to do popovers/form helpers. If you don't really know what I am talking about, this is what I am referring to:
http://www.ashrobbins.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/sliding-form-helpers.png

I will like to do something like the following:

#1: User position is the red square. And the yellow squares are related, so I the big yellow square is displaying information about the first squares. Here's what I mean:
http://postimage.org/image/wgzedx2fv/

PS: Note that the box in the third column needs to be big!

#2
For this step, when the user goes to the second row (red square), I want the box in the third column to change to correspond to the second row's information. Hopefully this will help:
http://postimage.org/image/69y7hyk63/

I cannot figure out how to do this. I am currently using RoR and Bootstrap, but I am unsure if it has anything to do, it may simply have to do with CSS/HTML.

I have tried doing something like this for my html and it worked to some degree, but it doesnt look as good as I would want it to.

Anything will help.
Thanks!

Update:
As requested, I have some code like this:

`<div class="span4" style="margin-left: 0px; ">`

`<div class="span3" style="margin-left: 0px; ">here where the explanation will go</div>`

Or my RoR:

- View

`= render :partial => 'shared/unitrow', :locals => {:f => f, :main_input => :offwarfare, :input_label => "Offensive", :power => OFFWARFARE_POWER}`

- Partial

`%div{:id => "wrapper"}`

`=f.input main_input, :label => input_label, :input_html => { :class => 'unitinputstyle'}, :wrapper_html => { :class => "unitinputdiv" }`

`%=div{:class => "unitpricediv"}`

```
=power
```

`%div{:class => "clear"}`

Just for reference, I'm using HAML. I just can't style it properly here in SO...

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle with your code?

Comment: Where are you getting the information from? Do you want to dynamically display content based off of the selected input field?

Comment: Hi @BethBudwig, I added the portion of my code I think it's relevant.

Comment: Hi @JonMcIntosh, The information on the third column will be a description that will be static, ie, it won't change. 
What I want is something like:

Quantity of Product | Cost of Product | Name and Desc of Product

So if the user selects the quantity of product 1, then product 1's cost and name and description will show up in column 2 and column 3 respectively.

Comment: I'll hold off on answering your question until I know *exactly* what you need, but is this the kind of functionality you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/LQNS8/ (click inside each textbox)

Comment: Hi @JonMcIntosh, yes thats what I was looking for. Thanks!
If you want to, answer with your fiddle and I'll mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anything dynamic happening on the client side (like DOM Manipulation) you will want to use Javascript. I've written an example for you using a jQuery; but you're free to use whichever library you prefer (or none at all).

```
$("#interactiveForm input").focus(function() {
  var target = $(this).attr("id"); // Gets the ID of the focused input

  $("#infoBox p:visible").hide(); // Hides visible content (if any)
  $("#infoBox").find("p#"+target).show(); // Shows the paragraph with the corresponding ID
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LQNS8/
​